# Vagrant python [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, vagrant

I am currently having a problem with vagrant. I used it before for a number of tasks, but now when I do vagrant up and then vagrant ssh, everything seems to work ok. Then I navigate into the vagrant folder to run a python file and when I run it I get the following error:

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant$ python project.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "project.py", line 75, in 
app.run(host='0.0.0.0.', port=8080)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 841, in run
run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 720, 
in run_simple
s.bind((hostname, port))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I tried multiple times to restart vagrant, I also tried vagrant destroy and restarted the process. I manually deleted and powered it off a couple of times, but I always experience the same error. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't vagrant...  This line in the stacktrace shows there could be a typo in your python script

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0.', port=8080)
```

Should be

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```